# How to Ignore or permanently block the files, which contain date or date+time in their filenames, from being detected by Git as files added/modified

Tags: bash, git, git-bash, gitignore

As I mentioned in the Q-title, I have some files whose names contain either `date` string or date+time timestamp in their names which are in the project configured with Git.

File names with dates or timestamps(date+time) are like below:

```
....
....
FileName1_18-07-2022.php
FileName2_18-07-2022_10-28-17_PM.vue
FileNameOther1_18-07-2022_10-28-28_PM.vue
....
....
```

And there are more than 20s of such files, which I want permanently ignored from Git detection. Filename can have numbers but when they contain exact date format strings(like shown in the examples above) in their names they must not be detected by Git whenever created/modified.

I know there are 2 methods for this, one is `.gitignore` and other is in Project's `.git/info/exclude` and I know couple wildcards like `*` and `?`, but can't figure out how to block those files that have date or date+time in their names.

Anyone can help figure this out ?

**Note:** "_PM" or "_AM" are optional and apparently they would be only present if Filename contains full date+time string. And date or date+time strings will always be in exact pattern as shown in list above. No other pattern of date/date+time is there, positively.

Comment: only these two precise date formats? or should things like, say, `File4_2002-07-08.foo` or `File5_18-07-2022_22-28-28.foo` also be excluded? does the data have to appear immediately before a final extension? can similar filenames exist that don't actually contain dates (eg. `File6_31-06-2022.foo`)?

Comment: Yes so basically filename can have numbers but only when right next to filename, any string adhering to date format coming after that (separated by underscore if you noted) can make file candidate for ignoring permanently. So even File6_18-07-2022_22-28-28.foo is also candidate and so is File78_18-07-2022_22-28-28.foo. As these both and the ones you mentioned also contains exact date formatted strings after underscore

Comment: so `_PM`,etc is optional? better add that to question

Comment: I already mentioned "filename containing date or date+time strings in their names", so it makes it bit obvious that _PM will be optional and only consdered when whole date+time is there in the filename. Still let me add that as note anyway. Updated the question

Comment: Note that being listed in `.gitignore` does not actually stop a file from being committed. The set of files that are in Git's index at the time you run `git commit` are the set of files that will be in the new commit. Listing something in `.gitignore` tells Git that `git status` should not *complain* about it as an "untracked" file *if it is in fact untracked*, and also tells `git add` that en-masse `git add` operations should not *add* it *if it is in fact untracked*. (Untracked, meanwhile, means "not in the index", which is unfortunately a bit circular.)

Comment: In any case, regular expressions might be powerful enough to match only the patterns you want, but Git's `.gitignore` and `exclude` files use glob pattern matching, not full regex. You *may* be able to get close enough by listing multiple glob expressions: you'll need at least one for dates and at least one for times, if you want to exclude something with only a time or only a date.

Comment: If something that has a time always has a date, all you need to do is match dates, which will simplify things.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your `.gitignore`:

```
*_??-??-????[._]*
```

This will match files with a date followed by a dot or an underscore, and is unlikely to match anything else.

Comment: The question marks will match anything, so this would exclude `hello_ab-cd-efgh_world` for instance. That might be OK, but you can definitely tighten this up by using `[0-9]` in place of each question mark.

Comment: That's what I mean: a false match is possible but so is winning the lottery. This is just `.gitignore`, it's not application code. It doesn't need to be perfect. But sure, use `*_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][._]*` if you are paranoid. :)

Answer (score 1):

With the help of John Kugelman's answer and some of turek's nice suggestions from comments I came up with a pattern that won't have any issue from year 1000 until year 9999 ;).
So this perfectly matches all filename patterns that I have in my project and successfully ignores those files when this pattern is added in either `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude` file:

```
*_[0123][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][._]*.php
*_[0123][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][._]*.vue
```

If anyone wants to block all file extensions then they can use this:

```
*_[0123][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][._]*.*
```

Thanks both John and turek for help. Anyone having any suggestions or point-outs feel free to mention in comments below.

Comment: `[._]*.php` requires the file to have two dots before the extension.